# Code auto-complete does not work for one specific class

Tags: visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

Like the title says, my code isn't auto completing in one specific class in my project which is really terrible for a beginning programmer like me.

I've tried both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> and going to Tools -> Text Editor -> C# -> IntelliSense.  Here "Show completion list after a character is typed" is checked.

Note: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> does work in other classes, if that is of any help.

The relevant code is:

```
namespace AudioDevices.Devices
{
    class CdDiscMan : DisplayAudioDevice
    {
        private readonly int mBSize = 700;
        private bool isEjected = false;

        public CdDiscMan(int serialId)
        {
            base.SerialID = serialId;
        }

        public void Eject()
        {
            isEjected = !isEjected;
        }

        public int MbSize
        {
            get { return mBSize; }
        }
        public bool IsEjected
        {
           get { return isEjected; }
        }
    }
}
```

Upon request, a class in which the auto-complete still functions:

```
namespace AudioDevices
{

public class Track
{
    private category style;
    private int id;
    private string name, artist, albumSource;
    private Time length;


    public Track()
    {

    }
    public Track(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Track(int id, string name)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Track(int id, string artist, string name)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.artist = artist;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public string GetLength()
    {
        return length.ToString();

    }
    public int GetLengthInSeconds()
    {
        return length.Seconds +
            (length.Minutes * 60) +
            (length.Hours * 3600);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Add the code of another(small one) class in which intellisence working fine.. Also mention the file names of both.. Hope You will be answred. Also.. it is `ctrl+space`... not `ctrl+alt+space` needed

Comment: I hope you must have checked stackoverflow answers from this thread already.. https://www.google.com.pk/#q=intellisense+not+working+in+visual+studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your namespace is same for both classes.. If yes then restart (quit/start) the visual studio...

Comment: The proble was solved by restarting VS, thanks! The namespace wasn't the problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you either have forgotten to put a semicolon somewhere or you have made a syntax error somewhere. Please post your code so that I can tell you whats the problem.

Comment: Added the code, but Stackoverflow kept giving it a weird format, I'm guessing that's related to my problem?

Comment: Hehe Syed bro.. you can google it and find..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365549/why-use-readonly-in-c-sharp